# How to add rel atribute to the links in gutenberg gallery

Tags: wordpress, image-gallery, fancybox-3, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

How to make work fancybox 3 on my site. I used this code for old galleries:

```
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_link', 'rc_add_rel_attribute');
function rc_add_rel_attribute($link) {
global $post;
return str_replace('<a href', '<a data-fancybox="images" href', $link);
}
```

Now this code not working.

Answer (score 2):

```
add_filter('the_content', 'aggiungi_fancybox');

function aggiungi_fancybox($content) {
       global $post;
       $pattern ="/<a(.*?)href=('|\")(.*?).(bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)('|\")(.*?)>/i";
       $replacement = '<a$1href=$2$3.$4$5 data-fancybox="gallery" title="'.$post->post_title.'"$6>';
       $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
       return $content;
}
```

Comment: This function work well with data-fancybox attribute for fancybox 3. You can modify  the "title attribute".

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.